# Infinite history in centos gnome terminal

Tags: gnome, centos, gnome-shell, linux-terminal

I'm using Centos 5.x gnome terminal. I would like to know how to set the terminal to hold infinite history. It is possible in KDE terminal. Don't know how to do it in gnome.

Please help

Comment: Do you mean infinite scrollback?

Answer (score 3):

In Gnome Terminal, go to *Edit*, *Profile Preferences*, in tab *Scrolling*, and check *Unlimited*.

This will allow you to keep all console output and the commands you entered since you opened the console window.